# Concatenate multiple fields on submit into a single array/field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models: QuestionnaireResult and QuestionnaireOption.

The options are dynamic.

QuestionnaireResult has two columns: date_submitted and results. I want the results column to be some sort of array of the QuestionnaireOption and their value...

i.e.

```
option_id / value
1 / 50
2 / false
3 / true
```

I submit data using this form, however it's not complete and not working because I don't know what name to give the text_fields `(undefined method 'not_sure_what_to_name_this' for #<Admin::QuestionnaireResult:0x4a5ef9>`):

```
<%= form_for(@questionnaire_result) do |f| %>
  <% if @questionnaire_result.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@questionnaire_result.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this questionnaire_result from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @questionnaire_result.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <% @questionnaire_options.each do |questionnaire_option| %>
        <% if questionnaire_option.field_type == 'Textbox' %>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label questionnaire_option.option %><br />
                <%= f.text_field :not_sure_what_to_name_this %>
            </div>
        <% elsif questionnaire_option.field_type == 'Checkbox' %>
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label questionnaire_option.option %><br />
                <%= f.check_box :not_sure_what_to_name_this %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

What name do I give text_field and how do I go about saving the results and storing them in a column as an array? Or is there better ways of going about this?

Comment: Did you need more help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), where it says:

> 2.2 Binding a Form to an Object
>
> While this is an increase in comfort it is far from perfect. If Person
>   has many attributes to edit then we would be repeating the name of the
>   edited object many times. What we want to do is somehow bind a form to
>   a model object, which is exactly what form_for does.

It goes on to show examples and elaborate on the discussion.  So, the fields you use in the form_for are that model's fields.  To show an example, in:

```
<%= form_for Feed.new, id: "feed_add"  do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "Add Feed", class: 'formlabel' %>
    <%= f.text_field :feed_url, class: 'forminput', :autocomplete => :off  %>
<% end %>
```

the model is Feed and the text_field is :feed_url, so this updates Feed.feed_url.  It is returned to the controller in params[:feed]['feed_url'].

If you can show your model, I can advise further.

To follow up on the other part of your question, "how do I go about saving the results and storing them in a column as an array? Or is there better ways of going about this?", that's a bit different.

If what you want to do is build an array, you might want to use form_tag instead of form_for.  form_for is specifically for models.  form_tag is a more generalized interface for objects not necessarily models.  You can see that in the same [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html).  To show an example:

```
<%= form_tag feeds_path, method: 'get', id: "feed_search" do %>
    <%= submit_tag "  Search  ", feed_url: nil, class: 'formlabel' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], class: 'forminput', :autocomplete => :off  %>
<% end %>
```

Here, the value of :search is returned in params[:search].

Regarding how to do it, you should return this information to your controller where it can process it.  Views are for display.  The controller can easily build and process the array so that it can be used in its decisions and/or routing.

Comment: Did this help?  Did you have more questions?

Comment: Apologies for the time taken to review this, this was perfect. Thank you for your kindness and help!